# print results from a command line argument

Tags: php, shell, command-line, shell-exec

ok, last question and this script of mine is done :) i have pflogsumm installed on my mailserver and i have completed (completely ugly but functional) mail server admin script in php for use over an https connection from any browser. I want to run the following command and  show the results on the landing page when i log in:

```
pflogsumm /var/log/mail.log
```

this command works from the command line
i have tried exec() and shell_exec() and i get a blank screen.

Comment: is pflogsumm in the path of whatever shell PHP is using when it does the exec? Is your webserver' userID allowed to run that script? is it allowed to read the /var/log directory and/or the mail.log file? A script working at the command line but not from the webserver generally always boils down to a permissions problem.

Comment: its the program. and the log file show is the file it reads

Comment: `exec` returns: `The last line from the result of the command`. Use the output parameter.

Comment: well it turns out that shell_exec was the right thing to do, now that i have the filepath right for the executable. it shows it as a text wrap though and not a neat column like it does in the ssh session.

Comment: <?php 
    echo shell_exec('/usr/sbin/pflogsumm /var/log/mail.log');
    ?> was the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo shell_exec('/usr/sbin/pflogsumm /var/log/mail.log'); ?>
```

is the correct code apparently, all i had to do was to find the right path to the program. 
in a view source i get the statistics shown like they do in the command prompt but on the webpage it shows it as a run on sentence...